# Audio recording and client side error while converting Speech to text in Oppo

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

How to fix  `ERROR_AUDIO = 3(Audio recording error)` and `ERROR_CLIENT = 5(Client side error)` in speech recognizer while converting speech to text(Using custom dialog with timer for voice recording)

```
   speechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(context!!)
        speechRecognizerIntent = Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH)
        speechRecognizerIntent?.putExtra(
            RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM
        )
        speechRecognizerIntent?.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault())
        speechRecognizerIntent?.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 3)
        speechRecognizer?.setRecognitionListener(this)
```